# (SolidJS 1.7.8/ Vitest 0.34.4) Is there a way to test Portal component content

Tags: typescript, vitest, solid-js

I built a custom select with a popper made up of a Portal component. I want to make the coverage of that component with Vitest particularly the content of the popper. So I rendered the component with a mocked collection like this :

```js
const {queryByTestId, unmount} = render(() => (

<ComponentRoot options="[my_json_objects_collection]">
  <PopperOpenerComponent/>
  <Portal>
    ...content generated from my_json_objects_collection I want to test
  </Portal>
</ComponentRoot>

));
```

But unfortunately when I fire a click event on my *PopperOpenerComponent* no DIV is created in the document unless the click is well fired. So I decided to mock the Portal component like this :

```js
vi.mock('solid-js/web', async () => {
  const actual: Object = await vi.importActual('solid-js/web');
  return {
    ...actual,
    Portal: (props: ParentProps) => {
      const _chArr = children(() => props.children).toArray();
      function List() {
        return <ul><For each={_chArr.length ? _chArr : mockedSubAssetClassOptions}>{item => <li>{(item as SubAssetClassOption)?.label}</li>}</For></ul>
      }
      return <div id={"portal"}><List/></div>
    },

  };
});
```

But it seems that the ***props.children*** parameter is not well implemented this way because when I log the parameter that comes from mocked Portal function execution it's always empty while it's supposed to be the render of the collection passed to Root component.

Is there an efficient way to test the structure and data of the Portal content supposed to be generated from ***my_json_objects_collection***?

Comment: I regret that I have only one upvote to give...